# Modifying background color based on if statement

Tags: vb.net, select, if-statement

I am relatively new to vb.net coding.

I am looking to write a code that will modify the label (calculation result output) color based on some criteria.  I have a drop down menu with 2 options, Dust and Metal.

The color is not changing and i am not sure why.

This is the code;

```
Dim concentrationcheck As String = Form8.materialType.SelectedIndex
        Select Case concentrationcheck
            Case "Dust"
                If Val(concentrationValue.Text) < 4 Then
                    concentrationValue.BackColor = Color.Red
                    MsgBox("Add more suppressant or contact factory")
                Else
                    concentrationValue.BackColor = Color.Green
                End If
            Case "Metal"
                If Val(concentrationValue.Text) < 20 Then
                    concentrationValue.BackColor = Color.Red
                    MsgBox("Add more suppressant, or contact factory")
                Else
                    concentrationValue.BackColor = Color.Green
                End If
        End Select
```

Comment: What is happening? Any of your MsgBox's firing? Any errors?

Comment: no, there are no error boxes, but the formatting is staying as the standard transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectedIndex is a number, not the SelectedItem

```
Dim concentrationcheck As String = Form8.materialType.SelectedItem.ToString
```

Your `Form8` name sounds like the name of the form, and not the instance.  My guess would be to change it to me if this is all running in the one form:

```
Dim concentrationcheck As String = Me.materialType.SelectedItem.ToString
```

If nothing is selected, an exception will be thrown, so you might have to do a simple check:

```
If materialType.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
  code here
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for that LarsTech,  The color formatting is still not working.

Comment: @DwayneHeight "not working" is not a description.  Any errors?  Your `Form8` name is suspicious to me, since it sounds like that name of the form and not the instance.  My "guess" would be to change `Form8` to `Me`.

Comment: I have 8 Windows application forms, this one is form4 pulling data that was entered on form8

Comment: @DwayneHeight Then you need a reference to the "instance" of Form8.

Comment: I use globalvariables ( i was told this is bad practice, but my skill level means it was easier for me)  And called the form8.materialtype.selectedItem to a text box, and it shows "Dust" but the color formatting does not work.  So i know it is pulling the correct data there right?

Comment: @DwayneHeight Yes, global variables is a bad practice since it makes code harder to debug, the inevitable *spaghetti code*.  Both Dust and Metal make the concentrationValue either red or green, depending on the value of `Val(concentrationValue.Text)`, so what is that value?

Comment: i set this value to 2.5 to test, then adjust it to 8 or 25 depending on if dust or metal is selected.  but there is no formatting on the label

Comment: @DwayneHeight Just use the debugger and step through the code line by line to see what it's doing.  It's not clear from your code "where" this code is getting called.

Comment: Thanks LarsTech, I figured it out.  How do i give you rep on this!

Comment: @DwayneHeight You accepted the answer (thanks), but you need a little more rep to do any upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your drop down menu is combobox .. Try this ..

```
Dim concentrationcheck As String = Form8.materialType.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspicious of SelectedIndex in your original post.
SelectedIndex is an integer, not the value *at that integer location*.

SelectedValue might get you what you need.